# UITableView list selector color

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITABLEVIEW in my ui

the list is black, and its list selector is grey 
i want the list selector to be either black or transparent

I can't find the property that controlls that

what is this property?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell selectionStyle` property

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method add

```
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

in order to make the selection transparent.

I hope it helps.